# Why does transform with transition cause the whole page to repaint?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

First, open chrome devtools, trigger [image]

And then hover the first div, you will find that if you remove the `transition` property, only first div is repainted, but if you add the `transition` property, the **whole** page will be repainted, is there anyone could explain this?

```css
div {   
  width: 100px;   
  height: 100px;
}

div:first-child {   
  margin-bottom: 100px; 
}

div:first-child:hover {   
  transform: scale(1.4);   
  transition: all .3s;   
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div> 11111111111111111 </div>
<div> 222222222222222222 </div>
```

JSFiddle demo: https://jsfiddle.net/heaven_xz/4q2kgr2g/5/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: That's quite hard to answer, except for the ones that did build Chrome flash-painting tools, and the ones that did build Chrome painting algos. E.g FF doesn't behave like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 things that you should do to improve performance.

The first one is to declare only transition to the properties that you are interested to change.

But the root of repainting issue is that Chrome is now using the new style will-change. If you declare it adequately, the repaint will now be what you are expecting.

About the reason why the Chrome team decided to stop trying to optimize this automatically and rely on the developper declaring it, I have really no idea.

reference [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count)

[image: dev google page]

```css
div {   
  width: 100px;   
  height: 100px;
}

div:first-child {   
  margin-bottom: 100px; 
  will-change: transform, background-color;
}

div:first-child:hover {   
  transform: scale(1.4);   
  transition: transform .3s, background-color .3s;   
  background-color: red; 
}
```

```html
<div> 11111111111111111 </div>
<div> 222222222222222222 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the solution will resolve the chrome paint problem, but can't resolve the performance problem after I try

Comment: There isn't much more in terms of performance that can be done. Have you tried setting a transformz(1px) ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is still here

Comment: Thank you for this comment! You saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

This link can help with the issue. It gives the detail explanation of the transform property.

[Here's the link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/stick-to-compositor-only-properties-and-manage-layer-count)

Comment: It is better to put your suggestions in comments. Answers are generally intended to address the problem, to explain the scenerio, to solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried the link before I ask this question but don't solve the problem